# Create! method throwing nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My application checks for the user existing, and if they don't, it calls this line:

> p = Player.create!(uid: id, nick: session[:current_user][:nick], profile_complete: false)

which for some reason is throwing an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: Any luck with the posted answers?

Comment: Yes. Just selected proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally address this exception by sequentially checking whether `session[:current_user]`, then `session[:current_user][:nick]` exists:

```
if session[:current_user]
  if session[:current_user][:nick]
    p = Player.create!(uid: id, nick: session[:current_user][:nick], profile_complete: false)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the answer I think

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause:  `session[:current_user][:nick]`, what means that you do not have either session or current_user in the session in this moment.

You should check that the current_user exists before calling `.create!`

```
if session[:current_user] && (nick = session[:current_user][:nick])
  p = Player.create!(uid: id, nick: nick, profile_complete: false)
end
```

Comment: If `session[:current_user]` is nil, the second condition of the `&&` will not be evaluated, so the code works as expected.

Comment: No problem. In fact it is more readable to have this one-line condition that two if's annidated.

Answer (score 0):

in Rails you can also use method [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
p = Player.create! uid: id, nick: session[:current_user].try(:[], :nick), profile_complete: false
```